# Architecture design for a multi-tier web-application using delphi and firebird

Tags: database, web-applications, architecture, delphi-xe, multi-tier

I have an application that allows for searches, display of images, etc from a database.  This is written in Delphi running on a local database Firebird
I would like to make the application portable so that one could access the data from anywhere.
I need to know how to structure the whole system.  For example, the database could reside on a cloud server e.g. Azure and people can retrieve information from this via the internet.  However, the display UI must be able to display in various formats, based on query results and thus has some processing so that it cannot just be a web page.
My thinking is to use something like TMS WEB Core to do the display on any type of device and then an application based on TMS XData on the server to actually access the database.  Is this a viable architecture or am I totally clueless on how to implement such an application.
I also wondered why any remote application cannot simply connect to a cloud database for information.
If anyone has experience or could direct me to appropriate tutorials/resources I will appreciate it.

This is for a Delphi App running on mobile device or desktop, using a back-end Firebird DB.  Haven't tried much as I don't have an idea how to start.  Have investigated TMS WEB Core and TMS DataX

None yet

None yet

Answer (score 1):

TMS XData on the server and TMS Web Core for the front-end is not only a viable architecture but actually a robust and wise choice. Remote applications are not supposed to connect to cloud databases because of performance and security issues.

Having a REST API server is also a better architecture in the sense all your business logic resides in this server. If you connect from the client directly to the database you will have more business logic in the client which is not recommended as well.

Comment: Thank you.  Are there any suggestions regarding an appropriate cloud storage space/or hosting platforms such as Azure

Comment: @BennieCoetzer You can use any VPS, I'm not aware of any technical limitation. I like Amazon EC2 or Lightsail, but that's just a personal preference.